# How to programmatically inject CDI bean by class name

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a bean annotated with @Example. This bean implements some interface `IExample`. I want to programmatically inject this bean by using its class name, but I don't want to specify its qualifier. 
I get unsatisfied dependency error because it is searching for the bean with @Any and this bean has @Any and @Example, which does not satisfy for some reason.

Is this possible to do in CDI?

Comment: Why would you have a qualifier, and then insist on lookup without a qualifier? Just remove the damned qualifier, not so? Unless you have no control over this bean?

Comment: Let's suppose that I don't have control over that bean, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming you want to inject the interface

If a bean is qualified, then you need to inject the bean via its interface with its qualifier, thats how CDI works. Even if you use Instance you need to select the specific implementation by its qualifier, otherwise how is CDI supposed to know what implementation you want to have? It should have been qualified for a reason. Otherwise you can only iterate over all found implementations.

### Assuming you can use the class

If you can use the class, then inject the implementation class directly, then you don not need a qualifier. This works because a class is always unique, there can not be multiple implementations of a class, its is a implementation, unless the class is abstract.

Read this doc for understanding how type safe resolution works, maybe it helps to clarify things.

https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html